# How to show variable width images inside carouFredSel?

Tags: caroufredsel

When we set img width in css portrait photos stretch. When we don't set img width carouFredSel shows other images' parts next to the current one. How can we show only one (portrait) photo centered in a fixed width carousel?

----js------

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        width: '100%',

        items: {
            visible: 3,
            minimum: 1,
            start: 0,
            width: '100%',
            align:'center'
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 800,
            timeoutDuration: 3000
        },
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        pagination: {
            container: '#pager',
            deviation: 0
        },
        auto: {
            pauseOnHover: true
        }
    });
```

-------css------------

```
#carousel img {
display: block;
float: left;
/*width: 978px;*/
height: 652px;
background: white;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope that I'm understanding correctly. The following should centre the images while not resizing the containing element

```
    $("#carousel").carouFredSel({
    width: "auto",
    height: "variable"  
})
```

Whereas the following will resize the containing element to the width of the image

```
    $("#carousel").carouFredSel({
    width: "variable",
    height: "variable"  
})
```